# Driving in Taiwan (Taroko to Taichung)

Tags: driving, taiwan

Are there any restrictions on driving from Taroko to Taichung, over road 8 and 14甲 (or just road 8 through Baxianshan National Forest Recreation Area)?  Google Maps doesn't even direct all the way through road 8, presumably due to the roadworks near Te-Chi reservoir (where the Google street view ends), but the road might be passable now?

Does one need a permit for driving through Taroko National Park, similar to the one, one needs to apply for when hiking?

Also, as this is a mountainous area, is a simple economy hire car enough for this journey or the gradients might be a bit too much? Just asking as when I was in Thailand the hire car I had was really struggling to make some of the hills.

Comment: Asking for recommendations of anything is off topic here.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise this, so removed part of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post an answer to my own question, based on the information I received elsewhere.

The information about current condition of the mountain highways can be found on the [Taroko National Park website](https://www.taroko.gov.tw/en/Event/HighwayCondition).

There should be no major road works on Highway 8 now, given that Bus 6506 is running the entire highway from Taichung to Lishan.

No permits are required to drive through Taroko National Park.

Most sedan cars should be fine but one must be comfortable driving in snow/ice and using snow chains in case it has frozen over in winter months. Manual transmissions recommended in steeper sections especially between Xinbaiyang and Wuling

Comment: In 2022, Highway 8 is still closed to the public between Guguan and Techi (see [台8臨37便道](https://thb2museum.thb.gov.tw/tw/cp-1176-6371-2068a-4.html)), unless you live around Lishan or are taking Bus 6506. This is due to the road getting wiped out by successive natural disasters since 1999. The standard driving route between Taroko National Park and Taichung is still via Highway 8 and 14甲 (14A), turning at Dayuling. The authorities are aiming to open the road sometime between 2023 and 2025 again, of course at the mercy of the weather.